firewall not blocking even it should
I use AlmaLinux 9, I understand that there is new backend service nftables which can be managed by iptables-nft command, so I set some rules and my rule set looks like:
# Warning: table ip nat is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip nat {
    chain DOCKER {
        iifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        iifname != "docker0" tcp dport 8080 counter packets 3 bytes 180 dnat to 172.17.0.2:80
        iifname != "docker0" tcp dport 9001 counter packets 4 bytes 240 dnat to 172.17.0.3:9001
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.0/16 oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.2 ip daddr 172.17.0.2 tcp dport 9001 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.2 ip daddr 172.17.0.2 tcp dport 9001 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.2 ip daddr 172.17.0.2 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
        ip saddr 172.17.0.3 ip daddr 172.17.0.3 tcp dport 9001 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        fib daddr type local counter packets 236 bytes 12653 jump DOCKER
        fib daddr type local counter packets 39 bytes 1732 jump DOCKER
        fib daddr type local counter packets 39 bytes 1732 jump DOCKER
        fib daddr type local counter packets 23 bytes 1056 jump DOCKER
        fib daddr type local counter packets 23 bytes 1056 jump DOCKER
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority dstnat; policy accept;
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        ip daddr != 127.0.0.0/8 fib daddr type local counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
    }
}
# Warning: table ip filter is managed by iptables-nft, do not touch!
table ip filter {
    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 178 bytes 55546 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 178 bytes 55546 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 84 bytes 11338 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 7 bytes 420 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 87 bytes 43788 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 178 bytes 55546 return
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state established,related counter packets 195 bytes 18089 accept
        tcp dport 22 counter packets 2 bytes 120 accept
        tcp dport 443 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER {
        ip daddr 172.17.0.2 iifname != "docker0" oifname "docker0" tcp dport 80 counter packets 3 bytes 180 accept
        ip daddr 172.17.0.3 iifname != "docker0" oifname "docker0" tcp dport 9001 counter packets 4 bytes 240 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 87 bytes 43788 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 178 bytes 55546 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 87 bytes 43788 return
    }
}

that rule set is saved in /etc/sysconfig/nftables.conf so it is loaded everytime server restarts, as you can see in chain INPUT, everything should be dropped except port 22 and 443, so I tried to run testing nginx server on port 8080 and I can still access it as well, my firewall is not blocking anything.. why? even when INPUT policy is set to drop.
EDIT2:
so I read that docker use DOCKER-USER chain for user defined rules, so I did:
table ip filter {
    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-USER
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
        oifname "docker0" ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "docker0" oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "docker0" ct state established,related counter packets 184 bytes 27570 accept
        oifname "docker0" ct state established,related counter packets 85 bytes 28483 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-USER {
        counter packets 534 bytes 178277 return
        tcp dport 8080 drop
        tcp dport 9001 drop
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy drop;
        ct state established,related counter packets 584 bytes 54071 accept
        tcp dport 22 counter packets 8 bytes 460 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER {
        ip daddr 172.17.0.2 iifname != "docker0" oifname "docker0" tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        ip daddr 172.17.0.3 iifname != "docker0" oifname "docker0" tcp dport 9001 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 {
        iifname "docker0" oifname != "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 {
        oifname "docker0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }
}

and still doesnt work, I can access both ports 8080 and 9001, tried even to restart server.
EDIT 3:
changed my chain to this:
chain DOCKER-USER {
    tcp dport 8080 drop
    tcp dport 9001 drop
    return
}

restarted server and port 8080 is still accesible

Was that Nginx server running within Docker?

@grawity yes for testing purposes if I can access that port 8080, I started it like: docker run -d --restart always -p 8080:80 nginx


I started it like: docker run -d --restart always -p 8080:80 nginx

Then the traffic is not 'input' from the host OS perspective – it may look like it should be, but you have nat/prerouting rules which rewrite packets to instead go to a different IP address (the container's), having the host act as a router in front of the containers, and making it actually forwarded traffic (i.e. routed) which then falls under hook forward.
(In other words: the 'routing' step is where the decision between input vs forward is made, therefore it depends on the outcome of 'prerouting' chains.)

so if I want to block port 8080 and 9001 I have to set drop rule into chain FORWARD in table ip filter?

so I did "nft add rule ip filter FORWARD tcp dport 8080 drop" and website is still accesible

Yes (or maybe the DOCKER-USER chain). This filtering happens after the 'prerouting' NAT that Docker has set up.

Please take a look at your current forward rules: you have Docker-defined rules that explicitly accept traffic to those ports (in the DOCKER chain). Trying to add "drop" rules after those is useless – you need to block the traffic before it reaches those rules, e.g. at the top of the forward chain. (Iptables would use the -I option instead of -A.)

added edit in my post

added second edit

The same thing applies – note how DOCKER-USER has a return rule and you're adding stuff after it. Since that first rule is unconditional, processing always returns out of that chain immediately and your custom rules below it are never reached.

i get it, so I added edit 3, still 8080 is accesible

Because, as mentioned, forward filtering is after DNAT (or in other words DNAT is in prerouting and therefore before forwarding), and you have a dnat to 172.17.0.2:80 rule in prerouting, meaning that the traffic has actually become "dport 80" by the time it reaches the FORWARD or DOCKER-USER chains.

so what should I do? what is correct way to do it? how should it looks? so I should block port 80?

If you want to use the FORWARD chain (or any of its sub-chains), then you need to block port 80, e.g. ip daddr 172.17.0.2 tcp dport 80. Though with nftables it would also be possible to have a "prerouting" filter chain that does the blocking before NAT.

how is possible to have filter chain before NAT? because docker docs says that recommended way for setting custom firewall rules is DOCKER-USER chain
